# Initializing a 2 dimensional array of a class in another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class say ABC and I have to initialize a 2 dimensional array of type ABC into another class. I am bad at objective C. Tried lots of ways, but facing some errors.

Here is ----- Class ABC ------

```
@interface ABC : NSObject{
int a;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int a;

@end

@implementation ABC

@synthesize a;

@end
```

Here is another class say XYZ where class ABC needs to be intialized:

------ Class XYZ -----

```
@interface XYZ : UIView {

ABC *abc[16][16];
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ABC *abc;
@end

@implementation XYZ
@synthesize *abc[16][16];
@end
```

Please suggest what could be the correct syntax of initialization. I am getting various errors everytime I try to initialize it.

Comment: You might read this part of the Stack Overflow FAQ about posting code. It is possible that the errors that you get are syntax errors. Post the errors you get, and edit your question to fix code formatting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: As documented in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html , C-style arrays are not supported by declared properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use C style arrays (i.e. `ABC *abc[16][16]`), you’ll need to provide accessor methods in your XYZ class.

```
@class ABC;

@interface XYZ : NSObject
{
   ABC *abc[16][16];
}
- (void)setABC:(ABC *)anABC atRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column;
- (ABC *)abcAtRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column;
@end

@implementation XYZ

- (void)setABC:(ABC *)anABC atRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column
{
   [anABC retain];
   [abc[row][column] release];
   abc[row][column] = anABC;
}

- (ABC *)abcAtRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column
{
   return abc[row][column];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   NSUInteger row, column;
   for (row = 0; row < 16; row++)
      for (column = 0; column < 16; column++)
         [self setABC:nil atRow:row column:column];

   [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [] type arrays with properties as in XYZ - what you can do would be to create an NSArray or similar container and create the multidimensional array in that way